WSL Ubuntu 24.04: DISPLAY is not working
I installed WSL Ubuntu 24.04. But setting DISPLAY variable does not work, so no graphics application are running. Any help, please ?
miroi@MiroPhenomII-X6:~/.lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble
miroi@MiroPhenomII-X6:~/.export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
miroi@MiroPhenomII-X6:~/.xclock
Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
miroi@MiroPhenomII-X6:~/.

